# Reset the printing system

Tags: printing, configuration, etc

To debug some printing problems (printing through the usual printing dialog), I would like to reset the printing system to its initial state, cleanly removing all automatically and "manually" installed drivers and network printers, as well as reverting all other changes. How can i do it? Where is this configuration stored?

Would it be safe to remove the contents of `/etc/cups`, for example? If so, would it be enough?

If removing `/etc/cups` is not recommended, can its contents be stored and later restored?

---

Here are some details of the issue I observe.

After freshly installing Ubuntu 22.04, I can properly use automatically added Toshiba network printers the first time I connect to the LAN.

However, after restarting the machine, 2-sided printing does not work anymore (using the usual dialog and without changing printer options), and the automatically generated `/etc/cups/printers.conf` file contains many extra lines, including

```
Option sides one-sided
```

Comment: I should think purging and reinstalling `cups` ought to do that.

Comment: @Jos, what about the packages that depend on `cups`? How to be sure to keep them?

Comment: I can't think of any package that depends on `cups` and can't be removed and reinstalled. Can you?

Comment: @Jos, how can i get the list of all the packages that must be reinstalled if i reinstall `cups`?

Comment: You can do that with `dpkg-query`.

Answer (score 0):

You can systematically remove printers (from either versions 20.04 or 22.04) by selecting `Settings > Printers` and against the one(s) you want to remove select the cogwheel icon  [image]after which select `Remove Printer` from the drop down menu.

Comment: Will it remove all the manually installed drivers and all the other custom config? I would prefer a solution of manually emptying some system folders, or something like that.

Comment: This does not work with Ubuntu 22.04. The automatically installed network printers are removed automatically, but the printing system changes its behaviour after the first network connection.